# Pivot table with EPPlus with wrong column fields order

Tags: c#, excel, pivot, epplus

I created a pivot table that should have the following columns fields YEAR, MONTH and DAY.

Here's the code for the columns:

```
            //Column Year
            pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 2].Value.ToString()]);
            //Column Month
            pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 3].Value.ToString()]);
            //Column Day
            pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 4].Value.ToString()]);
            //Sort by the last column = day because if first row from data table is for example 10 all the other months start 10 in the columns fields and then after the 30/31 the library adds 1 to 9.
            pvt.ColumnFields[pvt.ColumnFields.Count - 1].Sort = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending;
```

**Results in Excel:**

**Columns Year > Month > Day** (OK)

[image: Picture1]

It works fine, but if I add another column at the beginning the grouping columns go wrong!!!

```
            //Column account
            if (addAccount == true)
            {
                pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 9].Value.ToString()]);
            }
            //Column Year
            pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 2].Value.ToString()]);
            //Column Month
            pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 3].Value.ToString()]);
            //Column Day
            pvt.ColumnFields.Add(pvt.Fields[sheet.Cells[2, 4].Value.ToString()]);
            //Sort by the last column = day because if first row from data table is for example 10 all the other months start 10 in the columns fields and then after the 30/31 the library adds 1 to 9.
            pvt.ColumnFields[pvt.ColumnFields.Count - 1].Sort = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.eSortType.Ascending;
```

**Results in excel:**

Columns : **Account > Day > Month > Year** (WRONG)

It should be: **Account > Year > Month > Day** (OK)

[image]

So, what it's wrong with this?